# Configuring WooCommerce Bookings for a purchasing a preset number of sessions/hours

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm developing a site for a tutoring service and they have 3 types of services they sell:

1. Hourly Tutoring
2. Package Deals (Buy 10 hours, get a reduced hourly price, customer chooses when to use each of the 10 hours)
3. Study Courses (Signup for a class with 10 preset meeting dates, customer doesn't get to choose dates, they are already set).

WCB works great already for Service 1, where people can just pick an hour or more and book it.

I'm wondering if someone could give me any insight as to the best way to setup service 2 where someone can buy a set number of hours and then request dates for them. 
And for service 3, can this be done through WCB or would it be better to just make a WooCommerce product and put the dates in the product description?

I'm new to WCB and it seems like it can do this, having someone book 10 sessions/hours and then schedule them at a later date.

I'm just not sure the best way to do it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think that is much more complicated than you expect for cases 2 and 3, because it's about bundled virtual products. I have done a similar but very different web shop, with another booking plugin. I had to develop a special credit plugin for woocommerce that was also a bridge with booking plugin. This was a very hard development. For your curiosity, [have a look here](http://www.co-oking.be). Have you tried yet to submit your needs to team support of WooCommerce Bookings plugin. They are the first source to get some insights. I can't really help you because i have never used WC Bookings yet.